# EF Core 6 ThenInclude as LEFT JOIN with One-to-One Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-6.0

I have a One-to-One relationship between 2 entities (Mapped to legacy MS SQL tables that I cannot change). The Primary Key `Id` property is the Foreign Key relationship. ie:

```
public class Location {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [...]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public LocationAddress LocationAddress { get; set; }
}

public class LocationAddress {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    public string Street2 { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

Using EF Core 6 I've learned you have to make the relationship `nullable` in order for `Include` and `ThenInclude` to use `LEFT JOIN`. Not all `Locations` have a `LocationAddress`. I tried using `public LocationAddress? LocationAddress { get; set; }` but that didn't work, nor did `public Nullable<LocationAddress> LocationAddress { get; set; }`

How would I rewrite my entities to work with `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: *Not all Locations have a LocationAddress* -- If `Location.Id` is the foreign key to `LocationAddress` EF thinks the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you expand on that? Maybe provide an answer with an example so I can try it and accept your answer if it works? Thank you!